# Missing data when NodeJS TCP client implementing generic-pool sends to Java TCP server

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, connection-pooling

I'm using [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) to send data from a NodeJS TCP client to a Java TCP server.

This is the relevant code in my NodeJS client entry point `blockEventListener.js` - full code [here](https://pastebin.com/eBM6iait):

```
function createPool() {
    const factory = {
        create: function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const socket = new net.Socket();
                socket.connect({
                    host: sdkAddress,
                    port: sdkPort,
                });
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.on('connect', () => {
                    resolve(socket);
                });
                socket.on('error', error => {
                    if (error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
                        //console.log(`Retry after ${poolRetry}ms`);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            socket.connect({
                                host: sdkAddress,
                                port: sdkPort,
                            });
                        }, poolRetry);
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
                socket.on('close', hadError => {
                    console.log(`socket closed: ${hadError}`);
                });
            });
        },
        destroy: function(socket) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                socket.destroy();
                resolve();
            });
        },
        validate: function (socket) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (socket.destroyed || !socket.readable || !socket.writable) {
                    return resolve(false);
                } else {
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return genericPool.createPool(factory, {
        max: poolMax,
        min: poolMin,
        maxWaitingClients: poolQueue,
        testOnBorrow: true,
        acquireTimeoutMillis: queueWait
    });
}
 
const pool = createPool();
const poolStatusReport = `pool.spareResourceCapacity = ${pool.spareResourceCapacity}, pool.available = ${pool.available}, pool.borrowed = ${pool.borrowed}, pool.pending = ${pool.pending}`;
 
async function processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid, configPath) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        let nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8");
        let processBlock;
 
        do {
            processBlock = ProcessingMap.get(channelid, nextBlockNumber);
            if (processBlock == undefined) {
                break;
            }
 
            if (pool.spareResourceCapacity == 0 && pool.available == 0) {
                break;
            }
 
            try {
                const sock = await pool.acquire();
                await blockProcessing.processBlockEvent(channelid, processBlock, sock, configPath);
                await pool.release(sock);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to process block: ${error}`);
            }
 
            ProcessingMap.remove(channelid, nextBlockNumber);
            fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(nextBlockNumber, 10) + 1);
            nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8");
        } while (true);
 
        processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid, configPath);
    }, blockProcessInterval);
}
```

This is the relevant code in `blockProcessing.js` - full code [here](https://pastebin.com/XkV1FX8S):

```
exports.processBlockEvent = async function (channelname, block, socket, configPath) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // some code
 
        for (var dataItem in dataArray) {
        
            // more code
            
            for (var actionItem in actions) {
                
                // yet more code
                
                for (var record in rwSet) {
                    // ignore lscc events
                    if (rwSet[record].namespace != "lscc") {
                        // create object to store properties
                        const writeObject = new Object();
                        writeObject.blocknumber = blockNumber;
                        writeObject.chaincodeid = chaincodeID;
                        writeObject.channelid = channelid;
                        writeObject.timestamp = timestamp;
                        writeObject.txnid = txnid;
                        writeObject.values = rwSet[record].rwset.writes;
 
                        writeToSocket(socket, writeObject, channelname, chaincodeID);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("---------");
        }
 
        // update the nextblock.nextBlock file to retrieve the next block
        fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(blockNumber, 10) + 1);
 
        socket.write('<END>\n');
        resolve(true);
    })
}

function writeToSocket(socket, writeObject, channelname, chaincodeID) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(`ChannelID: ${writeObject.channelid}`);
        console.log(`Transaction Timestamp: ${writeObject.timestamp}`);
        console.log(`ChaincodeID: ${writeObject.chaincodeid}`);
        console.log(`TxnID: ${writeObject.txnid}`);
        console.log(writeObject.values);
 
        let objstr = JSON.stringify(writeObject);
        socket.on('error', function(ex) {
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            console.log(ex);
            console.log(writeObject);
            console.log('=================================');
        });
        socket.write(objstr);
        socket.write('\n');
 
        var outputLog = path.resolve(__dirname, folderLog, `${channelname}_${chaincodeID}.log`);
        fs.appendFileSync(outputLog, objstr + "\n");
    });
}
```

And this is the code in my simple Java TCP server:

```
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        int n = 0;
        while (n < Integer.parseInt(args[1])) {
            new ThreadSocket(server.accept());
            n++;
        }
        server.close();
    }
}

class ThreadSocket extends Thread{
    private Socket insocket;    
    ThreadSocket(Socket insocket){
        this.insocket = insocket;
        this.start();
    }       
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        try {
            InputStream is = insocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null && !"<END>".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            String output = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("INCOMING: " + output);

            out.println(200);
            out.close();
            in.close();
            reader.close();
            is.close();
            insocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

When I run the programs, I expect to see all the data read by the client being sent to the server in full. Instead what I observe is similar to [this sample output](https://pastebin.com/YRcxzgTM). Initially, the information is intact. However, after the first five lines (I believe this is because I set my pool minimum size to 5), I start seeing gaps in my information. Crucially, I see `EPIPE` and `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` in my client output:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!!
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at /root/nodejslistener/accessreal/product/sdk/nodejs/blockProcessing.js:103:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.processBlockEvent (/root/nodejslistener/accessreal/product/sdk/nodejs/blockProcessing.js:16:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/nodejslistener/accessreal/product/sdk/nodejs/blockEventListener.js:185:39) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED'
}
{
  blocknumber: '427',
  ...more details...
}
```

Sample EPIPE error output:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!!
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:788:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:800:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at /root/nodejslistener/accessreal/product/sdk/nodejs/blockProcessing.js:124:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at writeToSocket (/root/nodejslistener/accessreal/product/sdk/nodejs/blockProcessing.js:109:12) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
{
  blocknumber: '426',
  ...more details...
}
```

I have a few questions regarding my current situation:

1. When I leave out the `.close()` statements in my Java server, I don't get any errors, but I only see the first five chunks of data. Subsequent data seems to be missing, but I don't see any errors in my client. Why?
2. What should I change in my NodeJS client and/or Java server so that I can successfully send all my data?

Comment: Rather than use your client, I would suggest using telnet to debut your server. Once it runs there, then hook the client and server together.

Comment: @NomadMaker I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: Telnet is a program that allows you to create a text connection to an internet address. This would allow you to log into the server as a client, but you'd have to type everything yourself. I've used this in the past to test servers and clients.